# Loading Highcharts series from XML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, highcharts

I am trying to populate a highchart series from an xml source using jQuery. The XML file is an export from RRDTool and has the following format:

```
<data>
<row><t>1347559200</t><v>2.1600000000e+01</v></row>
<row><t>1347562800</t><v>2.1504694630e+01</v></row>
<row><t>1347566400</t><v>2.1278633024e+01</v></row>
.
.
.
</data>
```

My approach was to load the data using jQuery and push the series to the chart:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "data/data.xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function(xml) {
        var series = {  data: []
                    };

        $(xml).find("row").each(function()
        {
            var t = parseInt($(this).find("t").text())*1000
            var v = parseFloat($(this).find("v").text())
            series.data.push([t,v]);
        });
        options.series.push(series);
      }
  });
```

I end up getting the following error:

> Unexpected value NaN parsing y attribute

I created a JSFiddle to demonstrate the code: http://jsfiddle.net/GN56f/

Comment: +1 for creating a fiddle

Comment: Could you add a console.log statement after your array is populated and verify that all of the v tags are numeric?

Comment: @Adrian a fiddle that doesn't reproduce the problem is useless

Comment: @Musa Yeah, I tried to run it, but there are problems with cross domain requests. What a let down...

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the cross-domain issue, the error is due to there being an existing empty series in the plot options. The initial series in the options should be set to:

```
series: []
```

instead of:

series: [{
            name: 'Temperature',
            data: []
        }]

The subsequent call to `options.series.push(series);` merely adds a new series leaving the empty one unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Problems:

- you forgot `var` before declare `options` and `chart`
- forgot `;` after end `options`
- Hava you tried to log `options` before pass to `Highcharts` ? You're passing the following `series`.

That's the expected result ? I think no.

```
series: [{
    name: 'Temperature',
    data: []
}, {
    data: [// data from xml]
}]
```

- You're creating the chart before complete the request, so `options.series.data.push` will not work, you have to use [setData](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#object-Series) to update dynamically, but there's a problem, you don't know how long the request you take, so I suggest you to create the chart inside the `success`.

Try the following.

```
success: function(xml) {
    $('row', xml).each(function() {
        options.series.data.push([t,v]);
    });
    //@todo: declare chart as global before the ajax function
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
}
```